# Using pre-compiled C shared library with JNI/NDK

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am currently developing a small demo Android application that has C++ integration. I'm using Android Studio 3.1.4 and my project has NDK support (Development environment is **Windows 10**).

The purpose of the application is to load a shared library (.so) file from storage (sdcard), then dynamically link the library.

Here are the steps I went through to create this application:

**1. Using GCC on Cygwin to generate the shared library**

These are the files I used to compile the library

**"sumLib.h":**

```
#define _MYLIB_H_
#define MAX_INPUT 25
extern double sum(double x, double y);
```

**"sumLib.c":**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "sumLib.h"
double sum(double x, double y) {
    return x + y;
}
```

Then I used these following commands to generate the library file:

```
gcc -shared -o sumLib.o -c sumLib.c
gcc -shared -o sumLib.so sumLib.o
```

**2. Load the library file on Android client**

I transferred the file into the sd card of the Android emulator (using Device File Explored) **(/storage/emulated/0/Download/sumLib.so)**

Here is the c++ code that reads the library and links it with the symbol **"sum"**:

```
extern "C" {
JNIEXPORT jdouble JNICALL
Java_com_example_user_demo_MainActivity_sum(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jdouble n1, jdouble n2) {
    void *handle;
    double (*sum)(double, double);
    char *error;

    char fname[PATH_MAX];
    strcpy(fname, internalPath); //internal path is a predefined string that points to the Download folder in the SD card
    strcat(fname, "/sumLib.so");

    handle = dlopen(fname, RTLD_LAZY);
    if (!handle) {
        __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "Creating handle", "Error creating handle");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    dlerror();

    *(void **) (&sum) = dlsym(handle, "sum");

    if ((error = dlerror()) != NULL) {
        __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "Error linking symbol", error);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    double result = (*sum)(n1, n2);
    dlclose(handle);
    return result;
}
}
```

Here is the Java code that calls the c++ function:

```
public native double sum(double n1, double n2);

// function was called after the click of a button
public void onClickTestBtn(View v) {

    // set up the text view to display the result
    TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.sample_text);
    double result = sum(134.3, 11.3);
    tv.setText(String.format("Result is %f", result));
}
```

This should theoretically call the **"sum" function** defined with c++ and use the library to look up symbol **"sum"** and perform the operation, but **dlopen** cannot create a handle from the file, it kept throwing errors.

Here is the error message:

```
"dlopen failed: library \"/storage/emulated/0/Download/sumLib.so\" needed or dlopened by \"/data/app/com.example.user.demo-fzNLN7tBu86LCNun1yLQlg==/lib/x86_64/libnative-lib.so\" is not accessible for the namespace \"classloader-namespace\""
```

I noticed at the end of the file address in the error message, they added a forward slash instead of back slash, does that have any impact? Also I am not sure what the second half of the error message means.

I've considered that GCC on Cygwin might be compiling on a different architecture than what the Android emulator is running on, but after I checked the file, I found that it was compiled for **x64** (according to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/358434/how-to-check-if-a-binary-is-32-or-64-bit-on-windows), I found **PE d+** from reading the file). For the emulator, I'm running the x86_64 image (API 27) and it printed out **x86_64** after I called:

```
String arch = System.getProperty("os.arch");
Log.d("Debug", String.format("system arch is %s", arch));
```

I have also checked if the file was accessible from the c++ environment, so I used

```
FILE *f = fopen(fname, "r");
```

and in the debugger, it did not point to null, it was pointing to something, **0x00007227dd414018** to be exact, is it safe to make the assumption that it found the file and can correctly read it?

I am not sure how to fix this error that **dlopen** gave me, as for the integrity and correctness of the library file, I have tested it with the following C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
int main(int agrc, char **agrv) {
    void *handle;
    double (*sum)(double, double);
    char *error;

    handle = dlopen("./sumLib.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    if (!handle) {
        printf("error opening file");
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", dlerror());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    dlerror();

    *(void **) (&sum) = dlsym(handle, "sum");

    if ((error = dlerror()) != NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", error);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("Sum is %f\n", (*sum)(13.3, 113.4));
    dlclose(handle);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    return 0;
}
```

It was able to correctly open the library, link the symbol and return the correct result.

What am I doing wrong that is making **dlopen** throwing that error?

Comment: I don't think apps are allowed to load .so files from the SD card. You may be able to load it if you first copy it to the app's private storage (though this seems like a bad idea from a security perspective). The second issue is that you're trying to use an .so file that was built using Cygwin's GCC. That library may have dependencies to libc or other libraries that aren't available on Android (Android has its own custom libc implementation). Why aren't you using the NDK to build all your native libraries?

Comment: @Michael I'm looking into using NDK to compile the library, that was my concern as well (Using GCC on Cygwin to compile), I did it because it was a bit more convenient to generate the shared library and I didn't really consider the different dependencies or libraries (which I should have)

Comment: @Michael is correct. Loading shared libraries from the SD card is not allowed as it poses a very easily exploited security risk.

Comment: @DanAlbert I have actually tried writing the file into the internal storage of the emulator and read it that way, the data of the library file was received from a local server I set up. The internal path I wrote the file into was "/data/user/0/com.example.user.demo/files", and it gave me the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to build your app for target SDK 23 or lower, and run it on emulator API 24 or lower. I believe that the failure you see is a manifestation of recent security measures. See *[Android 7.0 Behavior Changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes#ndk)*:

> Starting in Android 7.0, the system prevents apps from dynamically linking against non-NDK libraries.

Building the **sumLib.so** with host **gcc** compiler is not going to help, either. Even though the resulting library targets same **x86_64** ABI, the runtime environment on Android is completely different. Please use NDK toolchain. If you wish, you can use the standalone toolchain instead of **ndk-build** or **CMake** scripts.

Comment: This really helps! I will try to build the library using the NDK toolchain

Comment: I've created my own standalone toolchain and used arm-linux-androidabi-gcc to compile the library, is it normal that the file is significantly smaller than the file generated by Cygwin GCC (6kb compared to 131kb)? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You probably need a x86_64 toolchain, not arm.